# get error while file upload in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, intervention

I am trying to upload image in laravel. But when i upload it gives error.

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null

Here is my Blade file form

```
{{Form::open(array('url' => '/AddNewBlog','id'=>'blogadd' ,
   'method' => 'post','class'=>'form-row','files'=>true,
   "enctype"=>"multipart/form-data"))}}
```

And here is controller

```
 $imagename_bg = time() . '.' . $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
 $destinationPath = public_path('/uploads/blog');
 $thumb_img = Image::make($photo->getRealPath())->resize(750, 450);
 $thumb_img->save($destinationPath . '/' . $imagename_bg, 80);
 $photo->move($destinationPath, $imagename_bg);
```

Please help me how to resolve this problem.

Comment: What is `$photo` ?

Comment: this is name of variable which i post

Comment: you are using interventaion pacakage?

Comment: Can you please `dd($photo);` and see the result!

Comment: Is `$photo = $request->photo`  ?

Comment: yes i already added this  $photo = $request->input("blogimage");

Comment: Please show us complete function code, so that we can see it! Also, add your HTML code for file upload!

Comment: this is my full function

Comment: In your question, you have not added this: `$photo = $request->input("blogimage");`

Comment: @ParthSureliya Try `$photo = $request->file("blogimage");`

Comment: Try: `$photo = $request->file("blogimage");   dd($photo);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not able to understand your code. if you are looking for uploading image and resize using intervention package try this:-

```
if($request->hasFile('blogimage')){
if (Input::file('blogimage')->isValid()) {
    $file = Input::file('image');
    $img = Image::make($file);
    $img->resize(400,270);
    $name = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $destination = public_path('/uploads/blog');
    $ext = $name['extension'];
    $rand= time().str_random(6).date('h-i-s').'.'.$ext;
    $img->save($destination.$rand);
}
}
```

Or Without intervention pacakge:-

```
if($request->hasFile('blogimage')){
if (Input::file('blogimage')->isValid()) {
    $file = Input::file('blogimage');
    $destination = public_path('/uploads/blog');
    $ext= Input::file('blogimage')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $mainFilename =time().str_random(5).date('h-i-s');
    $file->move($destination, $mainFilename.".".$ext);
}
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks bro its work. Can you tell me how can i resize this image

Comment: have you install intevention package? @ParthSureliya

Comment: then follow my first answer with intervention pcakage for more info :- http://image.intervention.io/api/resize

Answer (score 1):

```
$photo = $request->file('file_name');
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to use this:

```
$photo = $request->file("blogimage");
```

instead of:

```
$photo = $request->input("blogimage")
```

Hope this will fixed your problem!